# Same codes but producing different pdf files after reinstalling MikTex

Tags: installing, arrows

Before re-installing MiKTeX in my computer I used the following codes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A0) at (4.04,0);
\coordinate (A1) at (2.93,2.79);
\coordinate (B0) at (-2.02,3.5);
\coordinate (B1) at (-3.88,1.14);
\coordinate (C0) at (-2.02,-3.5);
\coordinate (C1) at (0.95,-3.93);
\coordinate (O) at  (0,0);
\coordinate (An-1) at  (-2.64, 3.06);
\coordinate (Bn-1) at  (-1.33,-3.81);
\coordinate (Cn-1) at  (3.97,.75);

% Draw x and y axis lines
\draw [->, thick] (-4.51,0) -- (5.73,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,-4.43) -- (0,5.31) node [left] {$y$};

\draw[very thick] (O) circle (4.04cm);
\draw[blue, very thick] (A0) -- (B0)--(C0) --(A0);
\draw[blue, very thick] (A1) -- (B1)--(C1) --(A1);
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (B0);
\draw[very thick] (O) -- (A0);
\draw[very thick] (O) -- (A1);


\def\angleRadius{30pt}
    % draw the arc
    \draw[->,thick] let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(A1), 
        \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
        ($(\p1)!\angleRadius!(\p2)$) arc (\n1:\n2:\angleRadius);
    % draw the label
    \draw let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(A1), 
         \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
         (\p1)+(\n1/2+\n2/2:\angleRadius) node[right] {$\beta$};

\def\angleRadius{15pt}
    \draw[thick] let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(B0), 
        \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
        ($(\p1)!\angleRadius!(\p2)$) arc (\n1:\n2:\angleRadius);
    \draw[dashed] let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(A1), 
         \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
         (\p1)+(\n1/2+\n2/2:\angleRadius) node[above=15, left=-5] {$120^\circ$};


\shade [ball color = blue] (A0) circle (0.5ex) node [right=8, below=3] {$A_0$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (B0) circle (0.5ex) node [above] {$B_0$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (C0) circle (0.5ex) node [left=9, below] {$C_0$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (A1) circle (0.5ex) node [right=3] {$A_1$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (B1) circle (0.5ex) node [above=5, left=1] {$B_1$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (C1) circle (0.5ex) node [ below] {$C_1$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (An-1) circle (0.5ex) node [left=3] {$A_{n-1}$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (Bn-1) circle (0.5ex) node [below] {$B_{n-1}$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (Cn-1) circle (0.5ex) node [right] {$C_{n-1}$};

\shade [ball color = black] (O) circle (0.5ex) node [below=8, left=3] {$O$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produced

[image: Figure before re-installing MikTex]

However, it had a trouble when I was re-installing MiKTeX. The above codes gave

[image: Figure after re-installing MikTexe]

The problem is the arrows went to wrong positions. It seems that the trick for labeling angles doesn't work anymore. How can I fix this issue? The possible easiest way is to use another labeling trick. But I would prefer not to, since I drew many figures by using that trick. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: A recent update to the `pgf` (TikZ) package reversed the order of the arguments to the `atan2` math function. If I switch the arguments on all instances of `atan2` in your code, it gives the correct output.

Comment: Thank you @PaulGessler. It's correct. I'm happy for still using that trick but if I give someone the codes, the arrows will be appearred in wrong positions in their computers, right?

Comment: Which labeling "trick" are you referring to?

Comment: I believe that the only possibility is to define a new function, say `myatan2`, in different ways according to the version of PGF.

Comment: Dear @PaulGessler. You could look at the command `\angleRadius` on my codes presented above to see the labeling trick for angles.

Comment: Dear @egreg. Unfortunately I'm not familiar for defining new command. Could you try one for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `atan2` has changed with version 3, swapping the order of arguments. The reason is that in all implementation of this function, the *y* coordinate comes first, while in the old PGF version 2, the coordinates had to be given in the order *x-y*.

If you want a document that can be compiled with either version (2 or 3) of TikZ/PGF, you can define your own function that changes its behavior according to the version number.

Here I define, in the preamble, a function `Xatan2` which has the same syntax as `atan2` in version 3. When the document is compiled with version 2 of TikZ/PGF, the function calls `atan2` but swapping the arguments; otherwise it simply calls `atan2`.

I have accordingly changed your macro definitions, so that *y*-coordinates come first.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\def\IfPGFversionIIorIII{%
  \expandafter\getPGFv@rsion\pgfversion\@nil
}
\def\getPGFv@rsion#1.#2\@nil{%
  \ifnum#1<3
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\IfPGFversionIIorIII
  {\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Xatan2}{2}{\csname pgfmathatan2\endcsname{#2}{#1}}}% PGF version 2
  {\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Xatan2}{2}{\csname pgfmathatan2\endcsname{#1}{#2}}}% PGF version 3
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A0) at (4.04,0);
\coordinate (A1) at (2.93,2.79);
\coordinate (B0) at (-2.02,3.5);
\coordinate (B1) at (-3.88,1.14);
\coordinate (C0) at (-2.02,-3.5);
\coordinate (C1) at (0.95,-3.93);
\coordinate (O) at  (0,0);
\coordinate (An-1) at  (-2.64, 3.06);
\coordinate (Bn-1) at  (-1.33,-3.81);
\coordinate (Cn-1) at  (3.97,.75);

% Draw x and y axis lines
\draw [->, thick] (-4.51,0) -- (5.73,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,-4.43) -- (0,5.31) node [left] {$y$};

\draw[very thick] (O) circle (4.04cm);
\draw[blue, very thick] (A0) -- (B0)--(C0) --(A0);
\draw[blue, very thick] (A1) -- (B1)--(C1) --(A1);
\draw[dashed] (O) -- (B0);
\draw[very thick] (O) -- (A0);
\draw[very thick] (O) -- (A1);


\def\angleRadius{30pt}
    % draw the arc
    \draw[->,thick] let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(A1), 
        \n1={Xatan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={Xatan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)} in
        ($(\p1)!\angleRadius!(\p2)$) arc (\n1:\n2:\angleRadius);
    % draw the label
    \draw let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(A1), 
         \n1={Xatan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={Xatan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)} in
         (\p1)+(\n1/2+\n2/2:\angleRadius) node[right] {$\beta$};

\def\angleRadius{15pt}
    \draw[thick] let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(B0), 
        \n1={Xatan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={Xatan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)} in
        ($(\p1)!\angleRadius!(\p2)$) arc (\n1:\n2:\angleRadius);
    \draw[dashed] let \p1=(O), \p2=(A0), \p3=(A1), 
         \n1={Xatan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}, \n2={Xatan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)} in
         (\p1)+(\n1/2+\n2/2:\angleRadius) node[above=15, left=-5] {$120^\circ$};


\shade [ball color = blue] (A0) circle (0.5ex) node [right=8, below=3] {$A_0$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (B0) circle (0.5ex) node [above] {$B_0$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (C0) circle (0.5ex) node [left=9, below] {$C_0$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (A1) circle (0.5ex) node [right=3] {$A_1$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (B1) circle (0.5ex) node [above=5, left=1] {$B_1$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (C1) circle (0.5ex) node [ below] {$C_1$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (An-1) circle (0.5ex) node [left=3] {$A_{n-1}$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (Bn-1) circle (0.5ex) node [below] {$B_{n-1}$};
\shade [ball color = blue] (Cn-1) circle (0.5ex) node [right] {$C_{n-1}$};

\shade [ball color = black] (O) circle (0.5ex) node [below=8, left=3] {$O$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result I get compiling with TeX Live 2012 (TikZ/PGF version 2.10) or TeX Live 2013 (TikZ/PGF version 3.0.0) is the same.

[image]

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you so much @egreg.