# Increasing thickness a portion of the circle's boundary in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn a circle in tikz and for two particular coordinates on the boundary of the circle I wish to increase the thickness of the circle's boundary. How can I do that?

A minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (2,0) circle (1.5);
%draw darkened arc from (0.58,-0.5) to (3.45,0.3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest if you know the angles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (2,0) circle (1.5);
%draw darkened arc from (0.58,-0.5) to (3.45,0.3)
\draw [very thick] (2,0) ++(210:1.5) arc[start angle=210,delta angle=-150,radius=1.5];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Though they can be calculated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (o) at (2,0);
\draw[-] (o) circle (1.5);
\coordinate (s1) at (0.58,-0.5);
\coordinate (s2) at (3.45,0.3);
\draw [very thick] 
let
\p1=(o), \p2=(s1),\p3=(s2),\n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)}
in
(o) ++(\n1:1.5) arc[start angle=\n1,end angle=\n2,radius=1.5];

\draw [very thick,red] 
let
\p1=(o), \p2=(s1),\p3=(s2),
\n1={ifthenelse(atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)<0,atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)+360,atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1))},
\n2={ifthenelse(atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)<0,atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)+360,atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1))}
in
(o) ++(\n1:1.5) arc[start angle=\n1,delta angle=\n2-\n1,radius=1.5];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So that doesn't seem to work perfectly in all cases. However, when using the second option, you can just subtract 360 from the `delta angle` to draw the arc the other way, i.e. `delta angle=\n2-\n1-360`.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (o) at (2,0);
\draw[-] (o) circle (1.5);
\coordinate (s1) at (2,-1.5);
\coordinate (s2) at (3.4,-0.5);
\draw [very thick] 
let
\p1=(o), \p2=(s1),\p3=(s2),\n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)}
in
(o) ++(\n1:1.5) arc[start angle=\n1,end angle=\n2,radius=1.5];

\draw [very thick,red] 
let
\p1=(o), \p2=(s1),\p3=(s2),
\n1={ifthenelse(atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)<0,atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)+360,atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1))},
\n2={ifthenelse(atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)<0,atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)+360,atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1))}
in
(o) ++(\n1:1.5) arc[start angle=\n1,delta angle=\n2-\n1-360,radius=1.5];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get to know the angles? (Besides the case you mentioned I have more coordinates.)

Comment: @Shahab Trigonometry?

Comment: @shahab, Be careful that `atan2` switched it's argument between v2 and v3....

Comment: @Rmano What Rmano meant is that in version 2.x of `pgf`/TikZ, the call to `atan2` should be `atan2(x,y)`, while in version 3 it's `atan2(y,x)`. Sorry about the lack of explanations, a bit short on time at the moment, might add later.

Comment: There is a nice macro form @egreg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174986/38080 that solve the thing --- IMHO PGFv3 should have called the function `atn2` and let the old one as it was, without naming it any more in docs... but well. I really like the `pgfplots` way of handling these things.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Your solution is not working for (2,-1.5) and (3.4,-0.5). It is only drawing the arc one way.

Comment: @Shahab Oops, so it doesn't work in all cases. Anyway, just subtract 360 in the `delta angle` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Clipping is another easy option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0.58,-.5);
\coordinate (b) at (3.45,0.3);
\draw[-] (2,0) circle (1.5);
\draw (a) circle (0.1);
\draw (b) circle (0.1);
\begin{scope}
    \clip (a) -- (b) -- ++(80:1.5) -- ++(180:4) -- cycle;
    \draw[very thick,red] (2,0) circle (1.5);
\end{scope}
%draw darkened arc from (0.58,-0.5) to (3.45,0.3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]