# Unexpected behavior of atan2() function with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot, atan2

Hi I'd like to draw some Bode-like plots,
the atan2() function seems to not work correctly at some combination of values.
I managed to re-create the minimal working code to show the problem:

I am using atan2() function with a non trivial dependence on x and some parameters defined as declare `function=`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
            d=0.9;
            Rl=100e3;
            L=200e-6;
            C=400e-9;
            wo= (1-d)/sqrt(L*C);
            Q=wo*Rl*C;
        }
    ]
        \begin{axis}[xmode=log]
            \addplot[domain=1e1:1e7, samples=1000] {-atan2(x/wo/Q,(1 - x*x/wo/wo))};
            \addplot[red, domain=1e1:1e10, samples=1000] {-atan2(x/wo,(1 - x*x/wo/wo))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

- `\addplot[red, domain=1e1:1e10, samples=1000] {-atan2(x/wo,(1 - x*x/wo/wo))};` gives an expected behavior up to some point (red curve);
- `\addplot[domain=1e1:1e7, samples=1000] {-atan2(x/wo/Q,(1 - x*x/wo/wo))};` does not seem reliable (black);

The following plot is informative:

[image]

It looks like that some combinations of `(y,x)` give a wrong behavior of atan2, i.e. step on right-hand side. Compiled with pdflatex (overleaf) and reproducible on other system.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I believe the first argument is supposed to be y, not x.  It comes from `atan(y/x)`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, well spotted. The argument order was changed from v2 to v3: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174986/38080

Comment: That is supposed to be the argument of a complex function z of x, that is z = 1 - (x/wo)^2 + i x/(wo Q). Therefore the argument is atan2(y,x) = atan2(Complex(z), Real(z)) = atan2(x/wo/Q, 1 - x*x/wo/wo) as in the code.